# XUL: how to allow access to top window from a browser script (when src is localhost)

Tags: javascript, xul

XUL:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin" type="text/css"?>
<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <browser type="chrome" disablesecurity="true" src="http://localhost:60000/test.html" flex="1" disablehistory="true" />
</window>
```

test.html:

```
<script>
    window.parent.document.title = "abc";
</script>
```

ERROR in jsconsole: `Permission denied to access property 'document'`

If I change `"http://localhost:60000/test.html"` to `"chrome://test.html"` then everything is OK, but in my case I have access throught a web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, you can not do what you want the way you want it.

Pages that are loaded from from non-`chrome://` addresses, or other Firefox extension specific protocols (e.g. `resource://`), operate within the security context of all normal webpages (non-privileged). One of the things which this explicitly prevents is access to areas of Firefox outside of the current page.Thus your attempt to access the parent of the current browser `window` should always fail.

The use of the `chrome://test.html` address in the browser's URL-bar explicitly instructs Firefox to load the page in the higher security context (privileged) of an extension where it has access to the majority of Firefox.

If you need to have access to `chrome://` resources from a non-privileged document it is possible to implement message passing using custom DOM events. However, on the privileged side you must have previously installed a Firefox extension into the Firefox profile in which you are doing this. In other words, the user has to have granted access to the privileged level by having gone through the process of installing an extension, or at least having accessed something from a `chrome://` address.  Such addresses are only available from a very limited number of folders on the user's local file storage.

There is a page at MDN on the [Interaction between privileged and non-privileged pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages) if you want to know more information.